# Random, inconsistent module error

Tags: angularjs, module, loading

I am currently doing some part-time development while studying and I have been tasked with fixing an error that I just can't wrap my head around.

I realize this will probably severely inhibit your ability to help me, but due to the nature of this being a disclosed project, I don't feel comfortable sharing code of the project and I don't know how to recreate this error without the entire project.

We use RequireJS for controllers, but not for services and third-party libs yet.

Onto the problem:
Once in like every 20-30 run of the application, it'll throw an unknown module error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module xx due to: 
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'xx' is not available!
```

What throws me off is the fact that it doesn't happen at all times. Not even close to! Most of the times, our app will run flawlessly.

With my little (read: no) information provided, is there anything you can advice me to check?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: might be at that time one of js file was not getting loaded..due to network issue..this sort of error don't come randomly

Answer (score 0):

In addition to pankajparkar's comment, to figure out the network issue, you may want to look into CDNs vs local copies of third-party scripts - for example, see **[this](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/downloading)** from the AngularJS Docs on downloading local copies.

Also, the specific error you have mentioned *"Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error"* is further talked about **[here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr)** in the AngularJS error Docs with a possible solution (patch) that may apply to your application.

Hope this helps! GL!

Comment: Actually, we are managing local files with Bower, rather than fetching a CDN.. When the error happens, I'm in a local development environment, provided by Webstorm.
Edit: Pardon my ignorance - I am self-taught with practical implementations and not as much theory. Can a network issue show in a local DE?